# Take part of string before known value

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string with hex values, for example:

```
01 02 03 AA BB CC FF 09 65 AA BB DE F2
```

And my need is take part of this string before first *AA BB*. I try do it with regular expressions. My ideas are around something like this:

```
(([0-9A-F]{2} )+(AA BB )){1}
```

And after match take first group. But it's not works. Could somebody help me with this task, please?

Comment: If you want to use a regex, use the one you have but  replace `+` with `+?`. Better, use something like `str1.Substring(0, str1.IndexOf("AA BB"));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your designed expression seems to be fine, maybe this slight modification

```
^([0-9A-F]{2}\s?)+(?=\sAA BB).*$
```

might work.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/MleS6b/1/)

Or if we wouldn't be validating, maybe these expressions would work:

```
^(.+?)(?=\sAA BB).*$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gQzfGd/1/)

```
^(.+?)(?:\sAA BB.*)$
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/wv6CcT/1/)

---

#### Edit

Or if the pattern might be repeating:

```
(.+?)(?:\sAA BB\s*.*?)
```

#### [Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/ajZdg0/1/)

Comment: This pattern "01 02 03 AA BB CC FF" may be just start of a string, and string may be longer. Also, "AA BB" may be presented further in a string. I need part before first "AA BB" in the string. Your solution is not working for me, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

If you change that regex to (([0-9A-F]{2}\s)+)(AA BB ) you can capture "01 02 03" in the first group